# IIS remove .html extension not working on folder file browse

Tags: iis

I am trying to remove .html extensnion during the browse in iis when i browse localhost that should show index or default html that is not showing and when i browse any file in folder with extension.html as o that says `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` thought the file exist.

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
<files>
<clear />
<add value="index.html" />
<add value="Default.htm" />
<add value="Default.asp" />
<add value="index.htm" />
<add value="iisstart.htm" />
<add value="default.aspx" />
</files>
</defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Hide .html ext">
<match url="^(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html" matchType="IsFile" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.html" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirecting .html ext" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.*).html" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
<add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*).html"  />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have URL Rewrite feature installed in your IIS.
[see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etqNO.png)

If it's not available, then click on **Get New Web Platform Components** on right hand side, search for **URL Rewrite** and install it. Reopen the IIS Manager.

Click on your site and open the URL Rewrite feature. You can explore your rewrite rules which are there in web.config file. [see example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOcFM.png)